# Whether 'var' allocates new memory when re-accessed or overwrites it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function Foo(){
  var someObj = {
    s: 'string'
  }

  console.log(someObj.s);
}

Foo(); // first call
Foo(); // second call
```

Will the memory where the `someObj` points to are overwritten or will a new one be allocated? If new memory will be allocated, what happens with `someObj` created at first call, will garbage collector erase it? And should I make a definition of `someObj` outside the function to reduce the number of memory operations?

Comment: It will be newly allocated everytime you call a function, when you call a function it will create a new context on execution stack every time and once the function return control back, that context will be poped out  of execution stack

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A new `someObj` will be created on each call of `Foo`. You can check this by returning the object and seeing if the new one is equal:

```js
function Foo(){
  var someObj = {
    s: 'string'
  };
  return someObj;
}
console.log(Foo() === Foo());
```

They're not the same - the location in memory that the first `someObj` points to is not the same as the location in memory that the second `someObj` points to. If you continually called `Foo` without leaving time for the GC to run, you would eventually run out of memory.

If the object is not returned, then after `Foo` runs, nothing else can reference the `someObj`, so it will be GC'd shortly.

If you want to prevent multiple `someObj`s from being created, yes, feel free to define `someObj` outside of `Foo`.

If you want `someObj` to only be referenceable inside of `Foo` while also creating only one such object, then turn `Foo` into an IIFE:

```js
const Foo = (() => {
  var someObj = {
    s: 'string'
  };
  return () => {
    console.log(someObj.s);
  };
})();

Foo();
```

Comment: `If you want someObj to only be referenceable inside of Foo while also creating only one such object, then turn Foo into an IIFE`  can you please elaborate this line more ? i don't think that we can access `someObj` outside of function even in OP's code

Comment: Right, it can't be accessed outside, but it's still created exactly once, ever, when the IIFE runs. It could also be returned from the inner function, if you wanted, but for something persistent, that doesn't make a whole lot of sense in most situations IMO

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned that's nothing I would really care when writing js. It's up to the compiler (V8 or whatever is compiling your code) to do necessary optimisations.

But:

> Will the memory where the someObj points to are overwritten or will a new one be allocated?

I says it's allocated every time function is called. Or, in other words, you can treat it as new variable all the time.

> what happens with someObj created at first call, will garbage collector erase it

Yes, when function is called and exits, this reference is marked as trash, which should be cleaned up by GC when GC kicks in.

> And should I make a definition of someObj outside the function to reduce the number of memory operations?

From my knowledge about V8 and similar, as longs as the type is always the same, there are some built-in techniques that would make this optimisation.

However, in general I cannot imagine how often this would have to be called, that you'd need any optimisation in this kind of code.

This question sounds like either some academic problem (which I probably can't help much) or some attempt of premature optimisations.

As a side note. Code is primarily for other humans. It should be readable for them first.

Comment: This function is called about 80,000 times, and object is bigger, so I’m so concerned about such things

Comment: I'd not move this var out of the functions scope unless I'd get 100% sure this would not get into race conditions with weird async. But make your benchmarks and see if it gives you any benefits.